# Getting the Variables of a function listed in the construct?

Tags: php

I'm not an amazing developer so please bear with me, but I've begun using classes and functions, and I really like how I can write a library. A single page where all my PHP can go. I was thinking though, my life would be a millon times easier if I could check the variables of a function in the construct, and escape them all before running the function. That way, I wouldn't have to escape each variable for each function.

I'd need to be able to have the construct somehow check and see what the variables are in the function, and then escape them.

```
so X = 'Variable for a function' 
   X = mysqli_real_escape_String($conn, X);
```

Could anyone please tell me if this is possible, and if not, what other options could you suggest?

P.S. I'm not advanced enough to use PDO yet, so please keep the advice to procedural programming.

Sorry, perhaps I'm not explaining this correctly. What I'm trying to do is eliminate the need to escape variables in my library that come when someone calls a function($vars). So the idea is to write some type of script within the __construct that will check the $vars and escape them before the function is ran.

```
class users
{
function __construct()
{
   //the idea is that i can somehow escape the variables within the function
   //for the function that's being called
    function magical_funtion_that_calls_all_variables()
    {
        foreach($var)
        {
            $var = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $var);
        }
    }
}

function register($user, $pass1, $pass2)
{
```

Comment: You're not advanced enough to use PDO?  Balderdash!  If you can use the horrible `mysql_` family, you can totally use PDO.  In fact, there's [a tutorial suited for helping people migrate](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) that should interest you.

Comment: @Charles He's not using the horrible `mysql_` family, he's using the improved `mysqli`. But that means prepared statements are available, so he should be using them.

Comment: @Barmar, I hate that sneaky letter i!

Comment: @Charles: That tutorial is great.  Thanks for posting it.  I added it to http://www.bobby-tables.com/php.html

Answer (score 1):

```
function escape_vars(array &$arr) {
  function ev(&$var) {
    $var = '*'.$var;
  }
  array_walk_recursive($arr,'ev');
}
```

That function accepts multidimensional arrays of values, passed by reference, and runs a function on each value in the array changing all the values. Don't do that.

Use prepared statements. There are procedural style examples here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

```
class users
{
  public function __construct()
  {
     //this is to set up the class you dont want to escape values until just before you
     // execute a query!
  }

  public function register($user, $pass1, $pass2)
  {
     // DO THE ESCAPING HERE
     $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $user);
     $pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $pass1);
     $pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $pass2);

     //now do your query
  }
}
```

Not 100% clear what youre asking but i think you just want to check the type so for example:

```
if(is_string($x)) {
  $x = mysqli_real_escape_string($x);
}
```

So in the context of a consutructor:

```
public function __construct() {
   $args = func_get_args();
   foreach($args as $key => $arg) {
      if(is_string($arg) {
         $args[$key] = myqli_real_escape_string($arg);
      }
   }
}
```

The problem with the preceeding example is now you have to use the numerically indexed `$args` array instead of any "named" parameters you might have defined in the constructor definition.

So really what you should do is manually check all the params. This shouldnt be that big of a headache because if you have more than about 5 youre doing something wrong.

That said using PDO or the OO api of Mysqli arent anymore difficult than using functions except in the case where youre trying to extend the classes. So I would still recommend using them. Even in a procedural context they make things much easier IMO.

Now in the case of your specific example you really should be using prepared statements which help with escaping as well as query (statement) reuse. Well mysqli is a litter harder to deal with here because it demands that things be references.

Comment: That would work, but listing each variable for all functions in the library into the construct wouldn't really eliminate work. The idea I'd like to do is make it where I never have to worry about escaping variables within the library again by grabbing all $vars and escaping them before each function is ran.

Comment: In what "construct"? can you ellaborate on that? Can you post an example of the class which will use this checking in its constructor?

Comment: What is the name of the "OO API of Mysqli" please? I've never heard of that, but I definitely wouldn't mind giving it a shot if i'm able to grasp it.

Comment: @VixenSoul: [Mysqli Dual procedural/object oriented API](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)

Comment: @sberry: No its not. PDO is an entirely different extension with an entirely different API. Though, I much prefer it to Mysqli because its easier to use and its more portable.

Comment: @prodigitalson: ah, didn't see the `Mysqli` reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are doing is a good solution. What happens if you wanted to pass a parameter that you don't want to be escaped? If the only *real* reason you want this is because you're lazy (which we all are...) then you could create your own "wrapper" method to escape the values in 1 easy call.

Such as:

```
class User
{
    public function register($user, $pass1, $pass2)
    {
        list($user, $pass1, $pass2) = $this->escape($user, $pass1, $pass2);
        ...
    }

    private function escape()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach ($args as &$arg)
        {
            $arg = myqli_real_escape_string($arg);
        }
        return $args;
    }
}
```

PS: As everyone else has suggested, I *highly* suggest using prepared statements. They are scary at first, but are extremely easy to get the hang of and eliminates potential security risks.

Although I don't recommend it at all, here is one way you could do exactly what you are looking for:

```
class User
{
    public function __call($methodName, $args)
    {
        foreach ($args as &$arg)
            $arg = myqli_real_escape_string($conn, $arg);

        call_user_func_array(array($this, $methodName), $args);
    }

    private function register($user, $pass1, $pass2)
    {
        // $user, $pass1, $pass2 will all be escaped
        ...
    }
}
```